# Bootstrap 4 - aligning nav bar items to right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am new to bootstrap. I went through many threads posted here on the same matter and tried out many different methods but had no luck.. I want the logo to be on the left and the navigation links to be aligned to the right. So far i have tried out:

1.placing the ul (.navbar-nav) inside a div with flex-container class with flex-direction: row-reverse;

2.Adding mr-auto class to ul (.navbar-nav)

3.Adding ml-auto class to ul (.navbar-nav)

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light boxed" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"><img src="images/techno_vision_logo.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Eyeglasses <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sunglasses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Lenses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Services
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Website link: http://www.codelabfiles.cf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your div(with id=navbarNavDropdown) is using display flex I added `justify-content: flex-end` to align items to the right and removed `mr-auto` to the inner ul element, now it's working.

Comment: Okay, mark it as the answer so that anyone who has the issue and comes across this question will know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make change in your class name on `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">`.

You have to replace the class `mr-auto` to `ml-auto`.

look at the snippet below in full-screen.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light boxed" style="margin-top:30px;">
  <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"><img src="images/techno_vision_logo.png"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Eyeglasses <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sunglasses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Lenses</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Services
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I hope this ans will help you to solve your issue.

Thank you...

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding ml-auto instead mr-auto as mentioned above.. but it didn't solve the issue. Why it wouldn't work is a big question for me because it was mentioned on many posts i read, that adding mr-auto should solve the issue.

Comment: its works perfectly I cant understand why its not working for you. because as per the code provided by you it works proper if you want to see then wait i will create snippet for your code in my answer.

Comment: you can see the snippet i have just edit my answer. i was just change the class name form 'mr-auto' to 'ml-auto'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some spacing from left and write, just change the following padding value. Otherwise, keep it 0. You will have to add the following CSS:-

```
.navber { padding: 0; }
```

And then you will have to replave this line:-

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

With :-

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

And this will solve your problem.